# AJAX POST to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having some issues trying to post data to CodeIgniter i have this.

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: $('#url').val() + "Dashboard/Index",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'post',
            data: {data: data},
            success: function( data ){
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
              console.log(jqXhr);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log( errorThrown );
            }
        });
```

Controller | Dashboard.php -> class: Dashboard, function: index

atm i'm trying with this only to see if something its posting, but no!

```
if($_POST) {
            print_r($_POST);
            die();
        }
```

So my whole controller looks like this...

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller 
    public function index()
    {

        // $test = $_POST['data'];
        // echo json_encode($_POST);
        if($_POST) {
            print_r($_POST);
            die();
        }


//////////////////////////////////Views///////////////////////////////// 



    // includes
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('includes/footer', NULL, TRUE);

    // App
    $data['menuProfile'] = $this->load->view('app/menuProfile', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['sidebarMenu'] = $this->load->view('app/sidebarMenu', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['topNavigation'] = $this->load->view('app/topNavigation', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['menuFooter'] = $this->load->view('app/menuFooter', NULL, TRUE);

    // Dashboard

    $dashboard['dinp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dinp', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['dispTitle'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dispTitle', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['porcentaje'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/porcentaje', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['temp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/temp', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['velocity'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/velocity', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dashboard', $dashboard, TRUE);


    $this->load->view('includes/head');
        $this->load->view('app', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/jquery');
    }
}
```

So the final output its just this:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)
```

I don't know why the post returns the whole HTML, i'm posting my data as objects, what should i do?

Comment: what is the value/content in 'data' used in ajax

Comment: _**[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]**_ its an Array (1) with 10 Objects

Comment: since you using datatype json, you need to convert data to json

Answer (score 0):

The data post contain the JSON object and you got an element of your object like this:

```
$this->input->post('your_post_element');
```

Comment: Ok, that would work if my ajax its success, but its getting an error because its getting the whole html, like this msg _**" SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0(…) "**_

Comment: Show your JSON before ajax, with JSON.stringify(data) and validate your obejct in this site: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to recheck what is inside this variable

```
data: {data: data},
```

2) You had set

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

so you have to return the contents in JSON format and also should set content type to JSON in the response page

```
$this->output
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode($_POST));
```